# Partition DELETE/INSERT concurrency issue in Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra which stores versions of csv-files. It uses a primary key with a unique id for the version (the partition key) and a row number (the clustering key). When I insert a new version I first execute a delete statement on the partition key I am about to insert, to clean up any incomplete data. Then the data is inserted.

Now here is the issue. Even though the delete and subsequent insert are executed synchronously after one another in the application it seems that some level of concurrency still exist in Cassandra, because when I read afterwards, rows from my insert will be missing occasionally - something like 1 in 3 times. Here are some facts:

- Cassandra 3.0
- Consistency ALL (R+W)
- Delete using the Java Driver
- Insert using the Spark-Cassandra connector
- Number of nodes: 2
- Replication factor: 2

The delete statement I execute looks like this:

"DELETE FROM myTable WHERE version = 'id'"

If I omit it, the problem goes away. If I insert a delay between the delete and the insert the problem is reduced (less rows missing). Initially I used a less restrictive consistency level, and I was sure this was the issue, but it didn't affect the problem. My hypothesis is that for some reason the delete statement is being sent to the replica asynchronously despite the consistency level of ALL, but I can't see why this would be the case or how to avoid it.

Comment: Generally speaking, C* is an eventually-consistent database. That means a lot of different things, but you can't rely on operation order. Never try to do some dependent operations in a row. It's better to redesign your schema and change your approach. If you post your data model and explain what you wish to achieve we may help you with that. As far as I can understood in your situation it's better to filter old versions after data retrieval on client side for example.

Comment: My expectations would be that the degree of eventual consistency would be limited by my choice of consistency level. Right now we are using ALL in our prototype for simplicity since it isn't a bottleneck. If I cannot depend on sequences of operations being completed in order with the most conservative consistency level, what can I then use consistency levels for?

Comment: ALL guarantees you that all the nodes have a consensus regarding the query (so after that single query all the nodes will have same version of the affected rows) but doesn't guarantee anything regarding queries' order. I would strictly suggest you to redesign your approach and stop considering C* as a relational database. That will not work.

Comment: According to the docs ALL will guarantee that it is written to the commit log on all nodes, which would guarantee the order given the associated timestamp (though Russell has a good point below regarding the assignment of these timestamps, but that can be solved in the queries).

Comment: Yup, but you can't guarantee the processing order... Anyway, performing all the writes with ALL consistency is a bad idea unless you have very small amount of writes. You may solve your problem and increase efficiency by redesigning your approach.

Answer (score 1):

All mutations are going to by default get a write time of the coordinator for that write. From the docs

> TIMESTAMP: sets the timestamp for the operation. *If not specified,
> the coordinator will use the current time (in microseconds) at the
> start of statement execution as the timestamp.* This is usually a
> suitable default.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html

Since the coordinator for different mutations can be different, a clock skew between coordinators can end up with a mutations to one machine to be skewed relative to another.

Since write time controls C* history this means you can have a driver which synchronously inserts and deletes but depending on the coordinator the delete can happen "before" the insert.

## Example

Imagine two nodes A and B, B is operating with a 5 second clock skew behind A.

At time 0: You insert data to the cluster and A is chosen as the coordinator. The mutation arrives at A and A assigns a timestamp (0)

There is now a record in the cluster

```
INSERT VALUE AT TIME 0
```

Both nodes contain this message and the request returns confirming the write was successful.

At time 2: You issue a delete for the data previously inserted and B is chosen as the coordinator. B assigns a timestamp of (-3) because it is clock skewed 5 seconds behind the time in A. This means that we end up with a statement like

```
DELETE VALUE AT TIME -3
```

We acknowledge that all nodes have received this record.

Now the global consistent timeline is

```
DELETE VALUE AT TIME -3
INSERT VALUE AT TIME 0
```

Since the insertion occurs after the delete the value still exists.

Comment: But what surprises me is that given that the delete is executed with consistency ALL, I would expect it to confirm the delete on all replicas before returning to the caller. Does this problem occur because it doesn't internally execute the DELETE before returning, but only logs it with a timestamp that then ends up being out of order with the next insert statement? The insert happens in batches I believe, so if each batch gets its own timestamp this would match well with my observations.

Comment: I can see that you supported setting the write time on the rdd-based connector API, but that feature seems to be gone from the dataframe-based API. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The delete is not "confirmed" it is "acknoweldged" the semantics are thus. A timestamp is applied to the mutation at the coordinator (one node) this entire mutation will look like

"DELETE X AT Time 5" 

This gets sent out to all the nodes

If you then insert and a different node is the coordinator and that node is clock skewed you may see

"INSERT X at 2"

Even if both of these messages are acknowledged by all the replicas and via your driver it looks like the two things happened in the order Delete -> INSERT

The confirmed log is

"DELETE
INSERT"

Comment: Updated example, We just haven't added the feature for dataframes yet

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar problem, and I have fixed it by enabling Light-Weight-Transaction for both INSERT and DELETE requests (for all queries actually, including UPDATE). It will make sure all queries to this partition are serialized through one "thread", so DELETE wan't overwrite INSERT. For example (assuming instance_id is a primary key):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (instance_id, instance_version, data) VALUES ('myinstance', 0, 'some-data') IF NOT EXISTS;
UPDATE myTable SET instance_version=1, data='some-updated-data' WHERE instance_id='myinstance' IF instance_version=0;
UPDATE myTable SET instance_version=2, data='again-some-updated-data' WHERE instance_id='myinstance' IF instance_version=1;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE instance_id='myinstance' IF instance_version=2
//or:
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE instance_id='myinstance' IF EXISTS
```

IF clauses enable light-wight-transactions for each row, so all of them are serialized. Warning: LWT is more expensive than normal calls, but sometimes they are needed, like in the case of this concurrency problem.